# Is there a way to add record counts to google sheet TAB name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I like to append record counts for each sheet to the tab name in google sheet.

The google sheet has a few tabs. (i.e `Sales`, `Inventory`, etc.)

I like the tab names to dynamically show the record counts in the tab name

Example: Tab names (`Sales-10`, `Inventory-100`)

I have searched and can't find a reference to how this could be done.

Thanks

Comment: [Sheet.setName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setName(String))

Answer (score 0):

Try below script:

Assuming, you have count values in **A1** in both sheets, if not then change your range accordingly in `getRange(1,1)`

```
function appendName() {
       
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  
  for (var i=0;i<sheets.length;i++){
      var oldName = sheets[i].getName();
      var getcountName = sheets[i].getRange(1,1).getValue();
      var re = /\W\d+/ ;
      var oldNameReset = oldName.replace(re , '') ;
      var setNewName = sheets[i].setName(oldNameReset + "-" + getcountName);
    }    
   
}
```

Set trigger **On Change**

Answer (score 0):

Assume counts in A1 or anywhere you want.  Don't use dashes in sheets that you don't want counts in.

```
function addCounts() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts=ss.getSheets();
  shts.forEach(function(sh,i){
    let idx=sh.getName().lastIndexOf('-');
    if(idx!=-1) {
      sh.setName(sh.getName().slice(0,idx+1) + String(sh.getRange('A1').getValue()));
    }
  });
}
```